# How to convert date time format in a Razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to display a date time string in the following format in a Razor view:

> 24 Jun'16

how can I convert the string in a Razor view?

Comment: No, but close @Satpal. `'` is a preserved character.

Comment: It's better to do this in your controller or in Javascript in case of problems. An attribute on your model's property would likely be best.

Comment: but getting error.

Comment: @JyothiLakshmi - when you get an error, please add it's message

Answer (score 4):

Just like you normally would:

```
@Model.YourDateTime.ToString("d MMM \\'yy")
```

The `\\` escapes the `'`, since that is a preserved character. The rest is quite straightforward.

Another option is the use of display attributes with `DisplayFor`:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM \\'yy}")]
public DateTime YourDateTime { get; set }
```